# Envío de mensajes vs Llamadas a funciones

Tags: poo, manejo-de-memoria, programación-funcional

Los lenguajes de programación orientados a objetos (como Java o c++) usan mensajes para hacer la computación, pero por otro lado los lenguajes funcionales (como Scheme o C) usan funciones.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre enviar un mensaje e invocar una función? Pienso que tiene que ver con la memoria asignada a cada una pero no estoy seguro.

Answer (score 1):

Yo distinguiría:

- **Funciones**: Casi todos los lenguajes tienen algo así como funciones. Una función es en esencia un conjunto de código con su propio "scope" (variables locales, que no se ven desde afuera), y que puede ser "llamado" (o invocado), pasándole uno o varios argumentos y que devuelve un resultado. Una función se considera "pura" si no tiene "efectos colaterales", y todo lo que hace es devolver un resultado que es función (determinística) de los parámetros de entrada. Es decir, que para las mismas entradas devuelve siempre el mismo resultado, y no hace más nada. Los lenguajes "funcionales" (`Scheme`, `Haskell`) son aquellos que se basan en este concepto de funciones puras. Lenguajes no estrictamente funcionales, como `C` , `Python`, `Perl`,  `Javascript`, tienen funciones, pero no exigen que sean "puras" (de hecho, frecuentemente no lo son - por ejemplo, pueden aceptar que no se le pasen argumentos, o que no devuelvan ningún resultado).

`Pascal` introdujo una especie de diferenciación explícita entre `function` y `procedure` (el primero correspondería a una funcion pura, el segundo solo ejecutaria codigo con efectos colaterales, sin devolver un resultado), pero este experimento no tuvo mucho éxito.

- **Mensajes**: En la teoría de POO, los objetos de comunican enviándose mensajes. En principio, cualquier objeto puede pasar cualquier mensaje a cualquier objeto, y este responderá (si corresponde) enviándole otro mensaje. Este concepto de **mensaje** es muy abstracto, y la mayoría de los lenguajes orientados a objeto se apartan bastante de esta abstracción. Smalltalk  es un lenguaje OO bastante "puro, y uno de los pocos que, puede decirse, realmente implementan el envío de mensajes. Lenguajes más populares (y menos "puros" desde el punto de vista POO) como Java, C#, C++, Python, etc usan **métodos**.
- **Métodos**: Son algo así como funciones, pero que están **asociadas a un objeto** (son "miembros del objeto"). Esto impllica que al ejecutarse "ven" el estado del objeto, y pueden acceder a variables -y métodos- que el "mundo externo" no puede ver). Además suelen soportar algún tipo polimorfismo: si el método no se encuentra en el objeto, se busca en el "padre" (y esta resolución ocurre en tiempo de ejecución). Estas caracteristícas hacen que llamar a un método de un objeto sea aproximadamente equivalente a "enviarle un mensaje".

Más aún: los lenguajes OO "impuros" como Java, C#, C++ suelen además soportar "métodos estáticos", que no están asociados a un objeto, y que en esencia son prácticamente funciones (pero no puras).

Answer (score 0):

En C las funciones son de ambito global, pueden ser llamadas desde cualquier lado y el resultado depende exclusivamente de los parámetros que se les pase.

En OOP los mesajes son funciones que que viven en el ambito de un objeto.

Un Objeto mantiene un estado interno dado por sus propiedades / atributos.

Cuando se necesita que se altere el estado del objeto, se ejecuta el método correspondiente sobre el objecto y a eso se le llama enviarle un mensaje.

Por otro lado y comparando con las funciones en C, el resultado de ejecutar un método no depende solo de los parámetros pasado al mismo, sino que también depende del estado interno del objeto.